# Button Disappearing on Resize

Tags: c#, wpf, layout, button, resize

In a WPF application I'm developing, I intend to have a number of buttons on the left in a separate grid, however, when I resize the application (making it smaller) the button shrinks and eventually disappears.

I know there's obviously something I'm overlooking, but I can't find out what it is.

Here's the XAML for that grid:

```xml
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left"
      Margin="0,23,0,0"
      Name="pnlNav"
      VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
      Width="200">
    <Button Content="Team Open"
            Height="31"
            Name="btnTeamOpen"
            Width="144"
            Click="btnTeamOpen_Click"
            Margin="26,44,30,533" />
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your button has a ridiculous margin: `Margin="26,44,30,533"`

This means the button has to be over 500px from the bottom, clippling occurs if the available space is smaller than the `top margin + height + bottom margin`.

([MSDN article on the layout system](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745058.aspx) & [Alignment, Margins & Padding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751709.aspx))

Comment: Thanks, that never even entered my mind!
I've changed it froma `Grid` to a `Canvas` which allows me to explicitly position the buttons. Thanks for the link, it looks like it'll be a big help